# What does the "friend" keyword mean in C++?

Tags: c++

Why do we need the friend keyword in this case?

```
friend bool operator=(const Stack&<E> s, const Stack&<E> q);
```

Comment: Is it operator = or operator==?

Answer (score 2):

It means there is an overload of operator= that is allowed to access the private members of Stack objects.

You could, in principle, do it inside your class, without the friend modifier, so the signature would be

```cpp
bool operator=(const Stack&<E> q) const; // The first operand would be this object
```

But be warned, operator= can't be defined outside class:
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PdHCSE)

Answer (score 1):

These "functions" are not called directly on the object like `x.y(z)` where `y()` is clearly a function call, but instead indirectly as when exercising `x = z`.

If that function needs to access `protected` or `private` internals of the object, which is a common thing, they need to be `friend` since they're considered "external" to the object.